# how to disable adding phone number in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable adding mobile phone numbers in the a textarea but not normal numbers and I couldn't success till now I've tried patterns but didn't work

Comment: What is the pattern of phone numbers?

Comment: You ill not know a sequence of numbers is a phone number until you have the correct number of characters. For example, if a user enters `4155551212`, this could be a phone number or the beginning of another sequence. So you may need to look for spaces after the number before you attempt to identify a number. But you also have 415 555 1212 or (415) 555 1212 or 415.555.1212 and this does not even look at more complex numbers like international or with extensions. Please include a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and maybe some examples of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and some examples of how you expect it to work. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but from your current question it doesn't sound like what you want is possible.

Comment: @rv7 any number more than 8 numbers.

Comment: Then try this pattern: `\d{8}` to check input value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to provide more information.
You can simply check the phone number from your textarea field with javascript.

```
var phonenumber = document.getElementById("yourTextAreaId").value;

//version 1
if (phonenumber.length > 8) {
    //valid phone number
} else {
    //non-valid phone number
}

//version 2
var pattern= ""; //insert suitable regex
if (pattern.test(phonenumber)) {
    //valid phone number
} else {
    //non-valid phone number
}
```

For a suitable regex, have a closer look at this link: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone+number

We don't know how you want to interact with the user, so we can't help you with that.